# How to avoid blank screen during page change in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile for an android application.
When I move from one page to another using

```
$.mobile.changePage($('#pageid'), {
            changeHash : false
        });
```

I notice a blank white screen for a very short duration.

How can I fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following property to your css: `.html{-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;}`

Please make sure it will be applied to full page.

Please also refer to https://quickleft.com/blog/4-steps-to-minimizing-rendering-issues-in-cordova-applications/

Comment: thanx 4 replying taranjeetsapra, but the solution didn't worked 4 me